# How does WhatsApp's Delete For Everyone work for photos?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, photos, delete

In WhatsApp, when the sender deletes a photo for everyone from their side, does it permanently deleted from my phone, or are they still there on my phone? If it was there, are they recoverable by the data recovery app downloaded from Play Store?

The phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 1):

When someone (e.g. an administrator, the sender) deletes a photo for everyone, **the respective file on the internal storage will be automatically deleted *when the recipients' WhatsApp is online***. This is a must for the WhatsApp app to receive the signal from the server in order to delete the file.

Thus, *that does not guarantee that no copy of the photo exists anymore*. One can set an automatic cloud backup for WhatsApp image folders so that every photo received will be backed up as soon as possible. Otherwise, when the recipient does not have an internet connection and the photo is still there, they can also make a local copy of the file somewhere else, whereas WhatsApp cannot touch the copy in both situations.

Comment: I don't touch the "data recovery app" part because I don't have any experience with it, and I'm also kind of skeptical of their performance.

Comment: Well I am the recipient and my drive backup is off and I did not make any copy it is just normally gone when I opened the photo and it is not showing in galary  . So my question is that the photo is somewhere in file manager or it is completely gone from my phone ? @Andrew T.

Comment: @Zai the file is completely gone. You can check it yourself by browsing to `/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images` using any file manager app.

Comment: Yes it was not there but I am confused as I downloaded a recovery app from playstore and scan the phone is it possible that it can extract it from some hidden folder in WhatsApp as there are many hidden folder there some folder which be can browse manually like .status but some are not possible to browse but they are within WhatsApp folder @Andrew T.

Comment: @Zai other apps (e.g. data recovery apps) cannot see something that the user cannot see. This is due to the Android security with app sandboxing and basic [file permission](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm). That's why I'm skeptical if data recovery apps on Play Store can even recover anything deleted in the first place.

Comment: Whether  it is manually deleted or automatically deleted it is good to go or there is any difference between manually deletion and automatically deletion ( Automatically deleted as the database file in WhatsApp deleted automatically after 7 days ) are both action same or automatically deleted are not as good as manually deleted and one more thing if a FILE or PHOTO is automatically deleted in a device with FBE ( Android 12 ) it's encryption key is also Deleted with it or not  @Andrew T.

Comment: Sorry, you're straying to another topic again. I won't entertain it in this comment thread.

Comment: OK LEAVE The encryption part can you please tell me Manually deleting or automatically deletion are same thing or automatically deleted is not as good as manual deletion @Andrew T.

Comment: @Robert through some light on this